# Ubuntu server support ethernet list

Tags: drivers, ethernet

Does ubuntu server 22 support erhetnet driver on asus prime b660m-k motherboard?

Comment: There is no "ubuntu server 22" release and how do we know which Ethernet adapter is installed in that motherboard?

Comment: Be aware the *flavor* of 22 isn't as complete as the main 22.04 Server product on which it's based.  22 & 22.04 are different Ubuntu products.